# Объясните, что делает эта часть кода

Tags: c#

```
    class Angar
    {
        System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<Task> Array;
        public Angar()
        {
            Array = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<Task>();
        }
        public System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<Task> Storage
        {
            get { return Array; }
            set { Array = value; }
        }

        internal Engine Engine
        {
            get => default;
            set
            {
            }
        }

        internal Engine Engine1
        {
            get => default;
            set
            {
            }
        }

        public static Angar operator +(Task obj, Angar obj2)
        {
            obj2.Storage.Add(obj);
            return obj2;
        }

    }
}
```

Объясните, что делает эта часть кода

Comment: Какая-то "недоделка" попытка написать класс-агрегатор.

Comment: сама по себе эта часть кода не делает ничего